# Is no soul doctrine (there is no eternal soul) supported in Buddhist suttas?

Tags: the-buddha, nirvana, enlightenment, anatman

"The purification of one's own mind/will (citta); this is the Doctrine
of the Buddha" [DN 2.49]

"How is it that one is called a 'Buddha'?...gnosis that the mind/will
(citta) is purified (visuddham)...such is how one is deemed a
'Buddha'." [MN 2.144]

[DN 2.157] "Gotama who is steadfast in mind (citta), inherently
quelled from all desires the mighty sage has passed beyond. With mind
(citta) limitless (Brahman) he no longer bears sensations;
illumined and unbound (nibbana), his mind (citta) is definitely (ahu)
liberated."

[SN 3.45] "The mind (citta) being so liberated and arisen from
defilements, one is fixed in the Soul as liberation, one is quelled in fixation upon the Soul. Quelled in the Soul one is unshakable. So being unshakable, the very Soul is thoroughly unbound (parinirvana)."

"The Soul is Charioteer"[Jataka-2-1341]

"I leave you now, having made my Soul the refuge (saranamatta) DN 2.120

"The Self (atman) as refuge, with nary another as refuge" DN 2.100

[KN J-1441] “The Soul is the refuge that I have gone unto”

“the body cannot pass that gate to fare beyond,..only the Soul (The Self)” -Udana

“Whatever form, feelings, perceptions, experiences, or consciousness there is (the five aggregates), these he sees to be without permanence, as suffering, as ill, as a plague, a boil, a sting, a pain, an affliction, as foreign, as otherness, as empty (suññato), as Selfless (anattato). So he turns his mind/will/spirit (citta, Non-aggregate) away from these; therein he gathers his citta (nous/spirit/mind) within the realm of Immortality (amataya dhatuya). This is tranquility; this is that which is the most excellent!” [MN 1.436]

[MN 1.511] “For a long time I have been cheated, tricked and hoodwinked by my citta. For when grasping, I have been grasping onto form, for when grasping, I have been grasping onto feelings, , for when grasping, I have been grasping onto perceptions, for when grasping, I have been grasping onto experiences, for when grasping, I have been grasping onto consciousness.”

SN 1.96 “The nihilist…goes to terrible hell…from darkness to darkness”

[SN 2.17] ‘Nonbeing (asat, natthiti [views of either sabbamnatthi ‘the all is ultimately not’ (atomism), and sabbam puthuttan ‘the all is merely composite (atoms)’ [SN 2.77] both are heresies of annihilationism])'”

Comment: dear @atman, welcome back to the site. Your questions are very valid and valuable - and I see where they come from, but please please please try to stay within the format of this web site. Do not post multiple takes on the same basic question. Do not post two-page-long questions. Do not post questions that are actually polemical statements. Do not post responses to answers as your own answers to your own questions.  And so on and so forth. Please be nice and we will try to address your (really, one) question the best we can. Thank you.

Comment: Buddha taught to only teach Dhamma to those who want it & listen attentively. Any answers provided should only be for the benefit of Buddhists so they can learn how to refute those of other sects.

Comment: I searched for SN 3.45 and it's completely non-existent. The quotes that are claimed to be from DN 2 are also not there. SN 3 only has 25 suttas. Similarly there's no MN 1.436 and no MN 1.511. The mentioned quotes are not even in MN 1.  All your verses are either fabricated or mistranslated. This question should be downvoted as it presents fake verses for polemical reasons.

Answer (score 4):

You don't understand the Buddha, do you... The moment you speak of a "soul", you're done, lost your way to nirvana.

Buddhism is all about "deconstructing" the -words-, thus demolishing all virtual dichotomies, ending the conceptual imputation. Why? Because it is a neutral monism!

Answer (score 2):

> *"The purification of one's own mind (citta); this is the Doctrine of the Buddha" [DN 2.49]*

Yes.

> *"How is it that one is called a 'Buddha'?...gnosis that the mind (citta) is purified (visuddham)...such is how one is deemed a
>   'Buddha'." [MN 2.144]*

Yes.

> *[DN 2.157] "Gotama who is steadfast in mind (citta), inherently quelled from all desires the mighty sage has passed beyond. With mind
>   (citta) limitless he no longer bears sensations; illumined
>   and unbound (nibbana), his mind (citta) is definitely (ahu)
>   liberated."*

Yes although there is a flaw in this translation about "sensations".

> *[SN 3.45] "The mind (citta) being so liberated and arisen from defilements, one is fixed in the Soul as liberation, one is quelled in
>   fixation upon the Soul. Quelled in the Soul one is unshakable. So
>   being unshakable, the very Soul is thoroughly unbound (parinirvana)."*

No.

> *"The Soul is Charioteer"[Jataka-2-1341]*

No.

> *"I leave you now, having made my Soul the refuge (saranamatta) DN 2.120*

No. The word here is 'self' used in conventional language.

> *"The Self (atman) as refuge, with nary another as refuge" DN 2.100*

No. The word here is 'self' used in conventional language.

> *[KN J-1441] “The Soul is the refuge that I have gone unto”*

No.

> *“the body cannot pass that gate to fare beyond,..only the Soul (The Self)” -Udana*

No.

> *“Whatever form, feelings, perceptions, experiences, or consciousness there is (the five aggregates), these he sees to be without
>   permanence, as suffering, as ill, as a plague, a boil, a sting, a
>   pain, an affliction, as foreign, as otherness, as empty (suññato), as
>   Selfless (anattato). So he turns his mind/will/spirit (citta,
>   Non-aggregate) away from these; therein he gathers his citta
>   (nous/spirit/mind) within the realm of Immortality (amataya dhatuya).
>   This is tranquility; this is that which is the most excellent!” [MN
>   1.436]*

[SN 12.61](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.061.than.html) states citta, mano & vinnana have the same impermanent nature.

> *[MN 1.511] “For a long time I have been cheated, tricked and hoodwinked by my citta. For when grasping, I have been grasping onto
>   form, for when grasping, I have been grasping onto feelings, , for
>   when grasping, I have been grasping onto perceptions, for when
>   grasping, I have been grasping onto experiences, for when grasping, I
>   have been grasping onto consciousness.”*

[SN 12.61](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.061.than.html) states citta, mano & vinnana have the same impermanent nature.

> *SN 1.96 “The nihilist…goes to terrible hell…from darkness to darkness”*

The nihilist believes in "self" or "soul". Refer to DN 1 & Iti 49.

> *[SN 2.17] ‘Nonbeing (asat, natthiti [views of either sabbamnatthi ‘the all is ultimately not’ (atomism), and sabbam puthuttan ‘the all
>   is merely composite (atoms)’ [SN 2.77] both are heresies of
>   annihilationism])'”

The above quote is incomplete.

The nihilist believes in "self" or "soul". Refer to DN 1 & Iti 49.

MN 115 states everything whatsever is an element (dhatu) in Buddhism.